# Coldfusion 11 developers edition URL rewrite

Tags: tomcat, url, url-rewriting, coldfusion

On my live site I am using web.config file with no problems.  However, on my local server running CF 11 developers edition it does not. I get a 404 error.  CF 11 dev edition appears to use Tomcat 7.0.52

I tried to get http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ working, but no luck. Couldn't access the CF admin
I am on the right track or way off?

Thanks for any and all help!

web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
 <rules>
  <rule name="Rewrite Articles">
   <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
<conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>      
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.cfm?alias={R:1}" />
  </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have the IIS Rewrite module installed on your "local server"? Without that installed, IIS will ignore the rewrite rules in the web.config file. The module does not come with IIS or Windows - you have to download and install it separately.

Comment: Hey Carl, 
Ah, that might just be it!!!! Thanks and I'll check into it and update you.

Comment: Yes, please let me know. I'll post it as an answer if that solves it.

Comment: @CarlVonStetten: when cf is installed as a standalone dev server uses Tomcat not IIS.  I tried to research to install CF dev locally with IIS but not having any luck.  I guess now maybe I need Tomcat url rewrite instead? I guess I prob need to learn IIS and install CF on top of it but not familiar at all with that.  Thanks for helping out here!

Comment: You can still connect ColdFusion to IIS if you want to. In the Adobe ColdFusion program group on the Start menu, look for the Web Server Configuration Tool. It's usually a good idea to try to set up your dev environment to match as closely to your production environment as possible.

Comment: See the Web Server Configuration docs for more information: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/web-server-management.html

Comment: @CarlVonStetten : thanks so much for your input.  I will read those docs and work on implementing locally and let you know how it goes.  Thanks again!